# How to search something using a keyword in man command (man nmap)?

Tags: shell-script, kali-linux, nmap

I want to find a specific command in help section e.g I want to know what is the sync command. How do I search in `man nmap` or `nmap -h`? I specifically do not want a list of all commands.

2nd quest.
I am scanning windows 2019 server, firewall is off. I even open Inbound and Outbound ports for test. but `nmap` result shows all ports as filtered. why?

Comment: One question = one question. Don't ask "2nd quest" in one question. When you have another question, then post it as another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your man pager. Default uses Vim-style key bindings. That means you need to press `/` to enter forward searching mode (`?` for backward searching).

You press `/` and then searching phrase (e.g. `/sync`) then press *Return*. It will take you to the first occurrence. Press `n` to go to next one, `N` for previous.